# Орехово-Зуево и прочие подобные названия

Tags: топонимика

Здравствуйте!
Я обратила внимание на то, что достаточно много населенных пунктов имеют названия, родственные названию Зуева: Орехово-Зуева, крымская Зуя и другие подобные. А каково происхождение всех этих названий?
Заранее спасибо

Answer (score 1):

Птица есть такая - зуёк. Она же изображена на гербе Орехово-Зуево.

Answer (score 1):

Город Орехово-Зуево возник путем слияния нескольких населенных пунктов: торгово-ремесленного села Орехово, фабричного местечка Никольское Покровского уезда Владимирской губернии и села Зуево Богородского уезда Московской губернии.

Существует несколько версий происхождения названия Орехово-Зуево. По одной из них оно произошло от дохристианских мужских имен Орех и Зуй. Другая версия объясняет это так: в Орехове по берегам реки были заросли орешника, а в Зуеве обитали болотные птички зуйки из рода куликов. Эта версия и отражена на гербе города.

http://travel.imhonet.ru/city/311826/about/

Фамилия Зуев -  «птичья» фамилия, так же как Зуйкин и Зуйков. Зуек, зуй – болотная птица из семейства куликов: «Бродит, что зуй по болоту». Но есть вероятность образования этих фамилий от слова зуя (зуй, зуд) – так на Владимирщине звали озорника, задиру, а в архангельских краях – мальчишку‑прислужника, кашевара. Явно одного корня с этими фамилиями Зудов и Зудин, поскольку зуд и зуда – тот же непоседа, егоза, елоза. Есть и глагол зудить: «дразнить, докучать». А зудкий, зудкой – тот, что зудит, свербит, чешется.

Зуй, зуек - областное название некоторых болотных птиц из рода куликов. Переносно: прозвище живого, подвижного человека. Есть поговорка: 'Вертляв, как зуй'. (Ф) Фамилия распространена повсеместно. Зуй - старинное мужское имя. Встречается в документах XV - XVII веков. (Н) В 'Ономастиконе' Веселовского отмечается: 'Зуй, Зуйко, Зуев встречается повсеместно'. Там же приводится еще одно значение: мальчик-кашевар в артели.

http://poimenam.ru/familiya/Зуев